# golang test for sub directories fails

Tags: unit-testing, go, package

In my use case I am setting up a single go test which runs all _test.go in all packages in the project folder. I tried to achieve this using `$go test ./...` from the src folder of the project

```
 /project-name
       /src
          /mypack
             /dao
             /util
```

When I try to run the test it is asking to install the packages which are used in the imported packages. For example if I import "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql", it might have used another package github.com/golang/protobuf/proto. I did not manually import the proto package. The application runs without manually importing the inner package. But when I run the tests it fails. But individual package test succeeded.  Do I have to install all the packages in the `$go test ./...` error manually?

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `go get -t ./...` first to get all test deps.

From the [`go test -h`](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies):

> The -t flag instructs get to also download the packages required to
>   build the tests for the specified packages.